# Function with invariant area under curve

Tags: integration, recurrence-relations, problem-solving, area

I'm trying to find a function $f$ that fulfills the following property: The area under the curve starting at some point $x_0$ with a width of $x_0$ should always be the same for all $x_0$. In other words: When I evaluate the integral starting from $x_0$ with a width of $x_0$ it should be the same as the integral starting from $\alpha x_0$ with a width of $\alpha x_0$, for all $x_0$. Setting $\alpha=2$ for simplicity gives:

$$ \int_{x_0}^{2x_0} f(x) dx = \int_{2x_0}^{4x_0} f(x) dx $$

Expressing this equation by the antiderivate $F$, with $\frac{d}{dx} F(x) = f(x)$ gives the following recurrence equation:

$$ F(4x_0) - 2 F(2x_0) + F(x_0) = 0 $$

I'm currently totally confused how to approach this problem, and I'm not even sure whether it has a solution (intuitively I was expecting some simple solution based on an exponential function), let alone, how to find all possible solutions to such a problem. Any hint in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The condition is for all $x$, we have
$$\int_x^{2x}f(t)dt=C$$
Or,
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^{2x}f(t)dt=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_0^{2x}-\int_0^x\right)f(t)dt=2f(2x)-f(x)=0$$
Then solve the function equation $f(x)=2f(2x)$ to get required $f$.

Comment: @bluenote10: Hint: the solution is not an exponential, it's simpler than that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint! Actually I already had that relation in some of my notes, but I was struggling again because I didn't know how to systematically get all solutions of this equation. I now see that $f(x)=x^{-1}$ is a solution, and it should be easy to prove that this is the only polynomial solution. However, is it also possible to show that it really is the *only* solution?

Comment: @bluenote10 $f(x)=\frac cx$ (including $f(x)=0$) are also solutions. No more.

Comment: @Shuchang Zhang: I just realized that this equation has a certain similarity to the [refinement equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refinable_function) in wavelet theory. I further realized that the Kronecker delta satisfies $\delta(x) = 2\delta(2x)$, so there really is another solution. I guess this implies that there is no trivial way to systematically find *all* solutions to this recurrence equation, or to prove whether one really has found all possible solutions?

Comment: @bluenote10 I think you meant [Dirac delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), where $\delta(ax)/|a|=\delta(x)$. However, $\delta(x)$ is not, in strict meaning, a function, instead a distribution. If you allow $f$ to be a distribution, you will find much more.